# how to check whether the link button visible in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to check the link button visible in jquery. Below code is not working?

```
 if ($('id*="LnkBtn"').is(':visible')) { // check visibility
                    if (!Validatechecked("SrvRgnMDD")) {
                        $('#<%=Valid.ClientID%>').html("*");
                        passtest = false;
                    }





 <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtn" runat="server" Text="Show Details" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        CausesValidation="False" OnClick="MktallocLnkBtn_Click" />
```

Comment: What doesn't work? And please show use the aspx code of your link button

Comment: I have updated the aspx code of button

Comment: @user1546173 can you show the generated HTML?  That would be more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing your selector - I'm assuming you want to use the attributes selector

```
 if ($('id*="LnkBtn"')
```

to

```
 if ($('[id*="LnkBtn]"') // <-- notice the brackets
```

Though if you are trying to target only one element.. Just use the ID selector

```
$('#LnkBtn')
```

You can read up on the different selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Checking for an [`id`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in jQuery is with

```
if ($('#LnkBtn').is(':visible')) {
...
}
```